# How to post application insights data to REST API instead of Azure from ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, appinsights

I have an ASP.NET Core 5.0 MVC web application and app insights enabled. I am trying to post application insights data to REST API, which I developed using nodejs.

My `appsettings.json` details are below. Here, API got trigger, but I'm not getting any body content (Insight's data).

Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "123",
    "TelemetryChannel": {
      "EndpointAddress": "http://localhost:3000/v2/track"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- You won't be able to get the data directly through the application as
  it will not send the application insights directly to you, but it
  will save it in the storage account in form of blob storage.
- What you can do is either get the data directly through the storage
  account or you can get data from the application insights.
- If you want to take data from the storage account, you will have to
  use `@azure/storage-blob` npm package with node js .

  ```
  const container = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
  const blockBlob = container.getBlockBlobClient(blobName); 
    const download = await blockBlob.download(0);
  ```
- you can get `containername` from the portal under containers section
  of the storage account.
- Another way would be to run a query in the application insights. This can be achieved by making http requests and the request has to be authenticated by either azure ad token or the access key which is in the portal.

  ```
   HTTP GET  https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/{appId}/query?query={query}
  ```

**Reference:**
[Export telemetry from Application Insights](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/export-telemetry-from-application-insights/) by Anton Fritz

[Export data using Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/query/get)